# Como puede escalar una matriz bidimensional

Tags: javascript

Como puedo escalar una matriz bidimensional dando como parametos el ancho y alto de una matriz?

```
getNumberScaled(number, width, height) {
        let splitNumber = number.split('');
        let selectedArrDigits = [];
        splitNumber.forEach(element => {
            let parseIndex = parseInt(element);
           selectedArrDigits.push(this.scale(this.arr[parseIndex], parseInt(width), parseInt(height)));
        });
        this.transformLcd(selectedArrDigits);
    }
    
    scale(array, width, height) {
        let scaled = [];
        array.forEach(element => {
            let row = [''];
            let vertical = Array(width+2);
            if (element[0] != '' || element[2] != '') {
                for (let x = 0; x <= height; x++) {
                    vertical.fill('',1,width+1);
                    vertical[0] = element[0];
                    vertical[width+1] = element[2] 
                }
                scaled.push(vertical);
            }
            for (let i = 0; i < width; i++) {
                row.push(element[1]);
            }
            row.push('');
            scaled.push(row);
        });
        console.log(scaled);
        return scaled
    }
```

Ya reescala la matriz solo que no lo hace como debe ser sino que lo hace de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y debe de quedar de la siguiente manera para que funcione correctamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para poder ayudarte hace falta que muestres lo qua hayas intentado, para tener un punto inicial desde el que comenzar. Puedes leer [mcve]. Tal como está redactada tu pregunta, parece que deseas que alguien lo haga por ti. Saludos

Comment: ya agregue codigo para que veas como lo estoy haciendo